# Message Bundle Spring MVC 3 from DB

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bundle, message

I'm using String MVC 3 and I need to be able to upload the label of my WebApplication from the database. Since I can not find a solution, any of you can give me a hand or instradarmi cm ² on a possible solution?

Thanks to all

Comment: I don't get it... Where is currently this "label of WebApplication", and where do you want to put it? Upload from where?

Comment: Now the labels are loaded from the properties file, I have to load them from the database. I can not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for applicable it for you or not, but you can try third party service to store translation files like https://l10n.ws it has integration with Spring Framework